# Qt: how to move textEdit cursor to specific col and row

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

I can get the current position in row and col via ***QTextCursor::blockNumber()*** and ***QTextCursor::positionInBlock()***. My question is that how to move the cursor to the specific position with row and col. like

```
setPosition(x,y) // The current cursor would move to row x and col y.
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Easy solution:**

Just move the cursor there:

```
textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor::Start); //set to start
for( <... y-times ...> )
{
    textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor::Down); //move down
}
for( < ... x-times ...>) 
{
    textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor::Right); //move right
}
```

moveCursor is also the goto-way if you need to "select" text for changing it. A similar approach without the loops is also at the end.

**A bit more explanation and maybe better solution:**

In theory a text has no "lines" like shown in GUIs but the `endline-character` (*`\n` or `\r\n` depending on operating system and framework*) is only just another character. So for a cursor mostly everything is just one "text" without lines.

There are wrapper functions to deal with this but I get to them later.  First you cannot access those directly via the `QTextEdit` interface but you have to manipulate the cursor directly.

```
QTextCursor curs = textEdit.textCursor(); //copies current cursor
//... cursor operations
textEdit.setTextCursor(curs);
```

---

Now for the "operations":

If you know at what position you want to go in the string you have `setPosition()` here.  This "position" is not in respect to vertical lines though, but the whole text.

This is what a multi-line string looks internally:

```
"Hello, World!\nAnotherLine"
```

This would show

```
Hello, World!
AnotherLine
```

`setPosition()` wants the position of the internal string.

To move to another line you would have to calculate the position by looking for the first `\n` in the text and add your x-offset. If you want the 3rd line look for the first 2 `\n` etc.

Luckily there is also the function `setVerticalMovement` which seems to wrap this and maybe is what you want to do. It moves the cursor vertically.

So you could do:

```
curs.setPosition(x); //beginning at first line
curs.setVerticalMovement(y); //move down to the line you want.
```

After that call `setTextCursor` like shown above with the cursor.

**Note:**

The order is important though. `setPosition` sets the position in the whole text. So `setPosition(5)` while maybe in the 3rd line will **not** set it to the 5th character in the line you are but of the whole text. So move the x-cordinate first then y.

---

You need to be aware of the lengths of the lines though.

```
some longer line
short
another longer line
```

If you now specify line 2 and column 7 it will be "out-of-bounds". I am not sure how `verticalMovement` here behaves. I assume the cursor will be at the end of the line.

---

When you use the `QTextCursor` class directly you can also use the move operations without the loops because they have an extra parameter to repeat the operations.

```
curs.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start);
curs.movePosition(QTextCursor::Down,<modeMode>,y); //go down y-times
curs.movePosition(QTextCursor::Right,<moveMode>,x); //go right x-times
```

Comment: @Tarod thx. considering the length of the question this may be a bit too much though :D

Answer (score 8):

I think the best way is via `QTextCursor`.

For example, if your `QTextEdit` is called `textEdit`:

```
QTextCursor textCursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();

textCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Down, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, x);
textCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Right, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, y);

ui->textEdit->setTextCursor(textCursor);
```

Where `x` and `y` are the required position.

Comment: you should move it to the start though at first.

Comment: Depends on the application. I don't know the initial state. But yes, it could be necessary.

Comment: well for consecutive calls at least.

Comment: This works great, because you don't have to make loops + add `.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start)`

Answer (score 0):

If the document layout uses 1 block per line (e.g. it's a `QPlainTextEdit` or the document contains text with very basic formatting), then you can set the position directly:

```
void setCursorLineAndColumn (QTextCursor &cursor, int line, int col, 
                             QTextCursor::MoveMode mode) 
{
    QTextBlock b = cursor.document()->findBlockByLineNumber(line);
    cursor.setPosition(b.position() + col, mode);
    // you could make it a one-liner if you really want to, i guess.
}
```

The major advantage over the Down + Right methods is it is much simpler to select text between two locations:

```
QTextCursor cursor = textEdit->textCursor();
setCursorLineAndColumn(cursor, startLine, startCol, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor);
setCursorLineAndColumn(cursor, endLine, endCol, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor);
textEdit->setTextCursor(cursor);
```

There's also a performance advantage, if relevant.